# how to add number into table array php saprfc

Tags: php, saprfc

[my table sap rfc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjwT.png)

how can I add number in front of ID? if ID contain 3 digits it will add 000 in front of ID, if ID contain 4 digits it will add 00 in front of ID, if ID contain 5 digits it will add 0 in front of ID. For an example

```
  ID   |   FEE   |      NAME     |   PERIOD
000711 |  204000 |  YUDI MANDALA |   201807
000790 |   84000 |  AGUS WAHYUDI |   201807
001171 |  151500 |    SARJANA    |   201807
```

my code:

```
if ($FI_HPs!=0) 
{
 $array = [];
 for ($i=1;$i<=$FI_HPs;$i++) 
 {
   $FI_HP = saprfc_table_read ($fce,"FI_HP",$i);  
   $id = $FI_HP['ID'];

   if(isset($array[$id])) 
   {    
     $array[$id]['FEE'] += $FI_HP['FEE'];
   } 
    else 
   { 
       $array[$id] = $FI_HP;
   }
 }

 foreach($array as $item) 
 {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$item['ID'].'</td>
    <td>'.($item['FEE']*100).'</td>
    <td>'.$item['NAME'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['PERIOD'].'</td>
    </tr>';
 }
}
```

Comment: [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use str_pad

```
foreach($array as $item) 
 {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.str_pad($item['ID'], 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) .'</td>
    <td>'.($item['FEE']*100).'</td>
    <td>'.$item['NAME'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['PERIOD'].'</td>
    </tr>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

$base = 100000 ;

'. substr($base+$item['ID'],1) .'